# api platform error on post Invalid value provided (invalid IRI?)

Tags: symfony, symfony4, bad-request, api-platform.com, iri

Working in a vuejs app with axios I have some data structured as follow:

```
{
  ...
  surgeries: [],//array of object
  patientDiseases: [
   {  
  date: a javascrtipt date,
  disease: /api/diseases/#id //This is a valid IRI provided by the api in a select
}
  ] //array of object
}
```

When I post this data set api-platform's response is Invalid value provided (invalid IRI?)

Here is the stack trace

```
{
    "@context": "\/api\/contexts\/Error",
    "@type": "hydra:Error",
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "Invalid value provided (invalid IRI?).",
    "trace": [{
        "namespace": "",
        "short_class": "",
        "class": "",
        "type": "",
        "function": "",
        "file": "G:\\6.programacion\\from git\\Veterinaria\\vendor\\api-platform\\core\\src\\Serializer\\AbstractItemNormalizer.php",
        "line": 177,
        "args": []
    }, {
        "namespace": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "AbstractItemNormalizer",
        "class": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Serializer\\AbstractItemNormalizer",
        "type": "-\u003E",
        "function": "setAttributeValue",
        "file": "G:\\6.programacion\\from git\\Veterinaria\\vendor\\symfony\\serializer\\Normalizer\\AbstractObjectNormalizer.php",
        "line": 261,
        "args": [
            ["object", "App\\Entity\\Disease"],
            ["integer", 0],
            ["string", "\/api\/diseases\/4"],
            ["string", "json"],
            ["array", {
                "groups": ["array", [
                    ["string", "patient"]
                ]],
                "collection_operation_name": ["string", "post"],
                "operation_type": ["string", "collection"],
                "api_allow_update": ["boolean", true],
                "resource_class": ["string", "App\\Entity\\PatientDisease"],
                "request_uri": ["string", "\/api\/patients"],
                "uri": ["string", "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/patients"],
                "api_denormalize": ["boolean", true],
                "cache_key": ["string", "e83f0aaf1c78a8d5386bc220724081e1"]
            }]
        ]
    }, {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Normalizer",
        "short_class": "AbstractObjectNormalizer",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Normalizer\\AbstractObjectNormalizer",
        "type": "-\u003E",
        "function": "denormalize",
        "file": "G:\\6.programacion\\from git\\Veterinaria\\vendor\\api-platform\\core\\src\\Serializer\\AbstractItemNormalizer.php",
        "line": 132,
        "args": [
            ["string", "\/api\/diseases\/4"],
            ["string", "App\\Entity\\Disease"],
            ["string", "json"],
            ["array", {
                "groups": ["array", [
                    ["string", "patient"]
                ]],
                "collection_operation_name": ["string", "post"],
                "operation_type": ["string", "collection"],
                "api_allow_update": ["boolean", true],
                "resource_class": ["string", "App\\Entity\\PatientDisease"],
                "request_uri": ["string", "\/api\/patients"],
                "uri": ["string", "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/patients"],
                "api_denormalize": ["boolean", true],
                "cache_key": ["string", "e83f0aaf1c78a8d5386bc220724081e1"]
            }]
        ]
    }, {
        "namespace": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "AbstractItemNormalizer",
        "class": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Serializer\\AbstractItemNormalizer",
        "type": "-\u003E",
        "function": "denormalize",
        "file": "G:\\6.programacion\\from git\\Veterinaria\\vendor\\api-platform\\core\\src\\Serializer\\ItemNormalizer.php",
        "line": 43,
        "args": [
            ["string", "\/api\/diseases\/4"],
            ["string", "App\\Entity\\Disease"],
            ["string", "json"],
            ["array", {
                "groups": ["array", [
                    ["string", "patient"]
                ]],
                "collection_operation_name": ["string", "post"],
                "operation_type": ["string", "collection"],
                "api_allow_update": ["boolean", true],
                "resource_class": ["string", "App\\Entity\\PatientDisease"],
                "request_uri": ["string", "\/api\/patients"],
                "uri": ["string", "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/patients"],
                "api_denormalize": ["boolean", true],
                "cache_key": ["string", "e83f0aaf1c78a8d5386bc220724081e1"]
            }]
        ]
    }, {
        "namespace": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "ItemNormalizer",
        "class": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Serializer\\ItemNormalizer",
        "type": "-\u003E",
        "function": "denormalize",
        "file": "G:\\6.programacion\\from git\\Veterinaria\\vendor\\symfony\\serializer\\Serializer.php",
        "line": 177,
        "args": [
            ["string", "\/api\/diseases\/4"],
            ["string", "App\\Entity\\Disease"],
            ["string", "json"],
            ["array", {
                "groups": ["array", [
                    ["string", "patient"]
                ]],
                "collection_operation_name": ["string", "post"],
                "operation_type": ["string", "collection"],
                "api_allow_update": ["boolean", true],
                "resource_class": ["string", "App\\Entity\\PatientDisease"],
                "request_uri": ["string", "\/api\/patients"],
                "uri": ["string", "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/patients"],
                "api_denormalize": ["boolean", true],
                "cache_key": ["string", "e83f0aaf1c78a8d5386bc220724081e1"]
            }]
        ]
    }, {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "Serializer",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Serializer",
        "type": "-\u003E",
        "function": "denormalize",
        "file": "G:\\6.programacion\\from git\\Veterinaria\\vendor\\symfony\\serializer\\Normalizer\\AbstractObjectNormalizer.php",
        "line": 334,
        "args": [
            ["string", "\/api\/diseases\/4"],
            ["string", "App\\Entity\\Disease"],
            ["string", "json"],
            ["array", {
                "groups": ["array", [
                    ["string", "patient"]
                ]],
                "collection_operation_name": ["string", "post"],
                "operation_type": ["string", "collection"],
                "api_allow_update": ["boolean", true],
                "resource_class": ["string", "App\\Entity\\PatientDisease"],
                "request_uri": ["string", "\/api\/patients"],
                "uri": ["string", "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/patients"],
                "api_denormalize": ["boolean", true],
                "cache_key": ["string", "e83f0aaf1c78a8d5386bc220724081e1"]
            }]
        ]
    }, {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Normalizer",
        "short_class": "AbstractObjectNormalizer",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Normalizer\\AbstractObjectNormalizer",
        "type": "-\u003E",
        "function": "validateAndDenormalize",
        "file": "G:\\6.programacion\\from git\\Veterinaria\\vendor\\symfony\\serializer\\Normalizer\\AbstractObjectNormalizer.php",
        "line": 259,
        "args": [
            ["string", "App\\Entity\\PatientDisease"],
            ["string", "disease"],
            ["string", "\/api\/diseases\/4"],
            ["string", "json"],
            ["array", {
                "groups": ["array", [
                    ["string", "patient"]
                ]],
                "collection_operation_name": ["string", "post"],
                "operation_type": ["string", "collection"],
                "api_allow_update": ["boolean", true],
                "resource_class": ["string", "App\\Entity\\PatientDisease"],
                "request_uri": ["string", "\/api\/patients"],
                "uri": ["string", "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/patients"],
                "api_denormalize": ["boolean", true],
                "cache_key": ["string", "e83f0aaf1c78a8d5386bc220724081e1"]
            }]
        ]
    }, {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Normalizer",
        "short_class": "AbstractObjectNormalizer",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Normalizer\\AbstractObjectNormalizer",
        "type": "-\u003E",
        "function": "denormalize",
        "file": "G:\\6.programacion\\from git\\Veterinaria\\vendor\\symfony\\serializer\\Serializer.php",
        "line": 177,
        "args": [
            ["array", {
                "patient": ["array", []],
                "date": ["string", "2018-11-27T13:03:00.000Z"],
                "disease": ["string", "\/api\/diseases\/4"]
            }],
            ["string", "App\\Entity\\PatientDisease"],
            ["string", "json"],
            ["array", {
                "groups": ["array", [
                    ["string", "patient"]
                ]],
                "collection_operation_name": ["string", "post"],
                "operation_type": ["string", "collection"],
                "api_allow_update": ["boolean", true],
                "resource_class": ["string", "App\\Entity\\PatientDisease"],
                "request_uri": ["string", "\/api\/patients"],
                "uri": ["string", "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/patients"],
                "api_denormalize": ["boolean", true],
                "cache_key": ["string", "e83f0aaf1c78a8d5386bc220724081e1"]
            }]
        ]
    }, {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "Serializer",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Serializer",
        "type": "-\u003E",
        "function": "denormalize",
        "file": "G:\\6.programacion\\from git\\Veterinaria\\vendor\\api-platform\\core\\src\\Serializer\\AbstractItemNormalizer.php",
        "line": 307,
        "args": [
            ["array", {
                "patient": ["array", []],
                "date": ["string", "2018-11-27T13:03:00.000Z"],
                "disease": ["string", "\/api\/diseases\/4"]
            }],
            ["string", "App\\Entity\\PatientDisease"],
            ["string", "json"],
            ["array", {
                "groups": ["array", [
                    ["string", "patient"]
                ]],
                "collection_operation_name": ["string", "post"],
                "operation_type": ["string", "collection"],
                "api_allow_update": ["boolean", true],
                "resource_class": ["string", "App\\Entity\\PatientDisease"],
                "request_uri": ["string", "\/api\/patients"],
                "uri": ["string", "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/patients"],
                "api_denormalize": ["boolean", true],
                "cache_key": ["string", "e83f0aaf1c78a8d5386bc220724081e1"]
            }]
        ]
    }, {
        "namespace": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "AbstractItemNormalizer",
        "class": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Serializer\\AbstractItemNormalizer",
        "type": "-\u003E",
        "function": "denormalizeRelation",
        "file": "G:\\6.programacion\\from git\\Veterinaria\\vendor\\api-platform\\core\\src\\Serializer\\AbstractItemNormalizer.php",
        "line": 272,
        "args": [
            ["string", "patientDiseases"],
            ["object", "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Metadata\\Property\\PropertyMetadata"],
            ["string", "App\\Entity\\PatientDisease"],
            ["array", {
                "patient": ["array", []],
                "date": ["string", "2018-11-27T13:03:00.000Z"],
                "disease": ["string", "\/api\/diseases\/4"]
            }],
            ["string", "json"],
            ["array", {
                "groups": ["array", [
                    ["string", "patient"]
                ]],
                "collection_operation_name": ["string", "post"],
                "operation_type": ["string", "collection"],
                "api_allow_update": ["boolean", true],
                "resource_class": ["string", "App\\Entity\\PatientDisease"],
                "request_uri": ["string", "\/api\/patients"],
                "uri": ["string", "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/patients"],
                "api_denormalize": ["boolean", true],
                "cache_key": ["string", "e83f0aaf1c78a8d5386bc220724081e1"]
            }]
        ]
    }, {
        "namespace": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "AbstractItemNormalizer",
        "class": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Serializer\\AbstractItemNormalizer",
        "type": "-\u003E",
        "function": "denormalizeCollection",
        "file": "G:\\6.programacion\\from git\\Veterinaria\\vendor\\api-platform\\core\\src\\Serializer\\AbstractItemNormalizer.php",
        "line": 204,
        "args": [
            ["string", "patientDiseases"],
            ["object", "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Metadata\\Property\\PropertyMetadata"],
            ["object", "Symfony\\Component\\PropertyInfo\\Type"],
            ["string", "App\\Entity\\PatientDisease"],
            ["array", [
                ["array", {
                    "patient": ["array", []],
                    "date": ["string", "2018-11-27T13:03:00.000Z"],
                    "disease": ["string", "\/api\/diseases\/4"]
                }]
            ]],
            ["string", "json"],
            ["array", {
                "groups": ["array", [
                    ["string", "patient"]
                ]],
                "collection_operation_name": ["string", "post"],
                "operation_type": ["string", "collection"],
                "api_allow_update": ["boolean", false],
                "resource_class": ["string", "App\\Entity\\Patient"],
                "request_uri": ["string", "\/api\/patients"],
                "uri": ["string", "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/patients"],
                "api_denormalize": ["boolean", true],
                "cache_key": ["string", "e83f0aaf1c78a8d5386bc220724081e1"]
            }]
        ]
    }, {
        "namespace": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Serializer",
        "short_class": "AbstractItemNormalizer",
        "class": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Serializer\\AbstractItemNormalizer",
        "type": "-\u003E",
        "function": "setAttributeValue",
        "file": "G:\\6.programacion\\from git\\Veterinaria\\vendor\\symfony\\serializer\\Normalizer\\AbstractObjectNormalizer.php",
        "line": 261,
        "args": [
            ["object", "App\\Entity\\Patient"],
            ["string", "patientDiseases"],
            ["array", [
                ["array", {
                    "patient": ["array", []],
                    "date": ["string", "2018-11-27T13:03:00.000Z"],
                    "disease": ["string", "\/api\/diseases\/4"]
                }]
            ]],
            ["string", "json"],
            ["array", {
                "groups": ["array", [
                    ["string", "patient"]
                ]],
                "collection_operation_name": ["string", "post"],
                "operation_type": ["string", "collection"],
                "api_allow_update": ["boolean", false],
                "resource_class": ["string", "App\\Entity\\Patient"],
                "request_uri": ["string", "\/api\/patients"],
                "uri": ["string", "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/api\/patients"],
                "api_denormalize": ["boolean", true],
                "cache_key": ["string", "e83f0aaf1c78a8d5386bc220724081e1"]
            }]
        ]
    }, {
        "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Normalizer",
        "short_class": "AbstractObjectNormalizer",
        "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Normalizer\\AbstractObjectNormalizer",
        "type": "-\u003E",
        "function": "denormalize",
        "file": "G:\\6.programacion\\from git\\Veterinaria\\vendor\\api-platform\\core\\src\\Serializer\\AbstractItemNormalizer.php",
        "line": 132,
        "args": [
            ["array", {
                "name": ["string", "perro"],
                "age": ["integer", 8],
                "specie": ["string", "\/api\/species\/1"],
                "breed": ["string", "\/api\/breeds\/1"],
                "birthdate": ["string", "2018-11-07T13:03:00.000Z"],
                "entrydate": ["string", "2018-11-23T13:03:03.182Z"],
                "gender": ["string", "\/api\/genders\/1"],
                "temperament": ["string", "\/api\/temperaments\/1"],
                "chip": ["string", "asdasd2asd"],
                "coatType": ["string", "\/api\/coat_types\/1"],
                "coatColor": ["string", "\/api\/coat_colors\/1"],
                "details": ["string", "m.cxvczxjkcxzvjklczv"],
                "status": ["string", "\/api\/status_patients\/1"],
                "client": ["array", {
                    "name": ["string", "Juan"],
                    "lastName": ["string", "Alberto"],
                    "secondSurname": ["string", "Asdasd"],
                    "email": ["string", "asdasd@asdasd.as"],
                    "phone1": ["string", "234234"],
                    "phone2": ["string", "24234"],
                    "clientType": ["string", "\/api\/client_types\/1"],
                    "sector": ["string", "\/api\/sectors\/1"],
                    "identificationCard": ["string", "98989898989"],
                    "address": ["string", "sdfsdfsdfs sdf sd5f sd"]
                }],
                "isActive": ["boolean", true],
                "surgeries": ["array", [
                    ["array", {
                        "name": ["string", "sdfa fsdf"],
                        "date": ["string", "2018-11-30T13:03:00.000Z"],
                        "patient": ["array", []]
                    }],
                    ["array", {
                        "name": ["string", "sdfa fsdf"],
                        "date": ["string", "2018-11-30T13:03:00.000Z"],
                        "patient": ["array", []]
                    }],
                    ["array", {
                        "name": ["string", "sdfa fsdf"],
                        "date": ["string", "2018-11-30T13:03:00.000Z"],
                        "patient": ["array", []]
                    }],
                    ["array", {
                        "name": ["string", "sdfa fsdf"],
                        "date": ["string", "2018-11-30T13:03:00.000Z"],
                        "patient": ["array", []]
                    }]
                ]],
                "patientDiseases": ["array", [
                    ["array", {
                        "patient": ["array", []],
                        "date": ["string", "2018-11-27T13:03:00.000Z"],
                        "disease": ["string", "\/api\/diseases\/4"]
                    }]
                ]]
            }],
            ["string", "App\\Entity\\Patient"],
            ["string", "json"],
```

As you can see the IRI is present in the request in every object of the array but api-platform still raising an error of Invalid IRI.

The entities are configured with cascade persist option

Do you have any advice on how could I resolve this situation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

have you been able to find the reason of this behaviour? I am just facing probably the same issue.

```
$ composer info
api-platform/core                        v2.3.5             Build a fully-featured hypermedia or GraphQL API in minutes
symfony/serializer                       v4.2.2             Symfony Serializer Component
```

If (in your example) `surgeries` is ManyToMany relation, you can easily use IRI and Entity gets created. If `patientDiseases` is OneToMany (in fact it is ManyToMany too, but with extra attributes), using of IRI inside of object collection returns Exception above. And the object normalization looks weird:

```
["object", "App\\Entity\\Disease"], -> $object
["integer", 0],                     -> $attribute, but here it uses key 0 from array/collection instead of 'disease'?!
["string", "\/api\/diseases\/4"],   -> $value
```

After many attempts I have been able to find just a workaround. The entity with expected name here `PatientDisease` has to be defined as ApiResource with at least mandatory GET itemOperation (which can be easily a dummy controller returning always "not found"). Then ApiPlatform probably understands better the format of object collection and new embedded entity gets successfully created.

I do not know whether this is an expected behaviour or a bug. But I hope this may help also others :-)